ssd not showing up on one pc but on second it does
I have a problem with my SSD. I wanted to have dual SSD dual OS PC (1TB NVMe — Windows, 256GB SATA SSD — Arch Linux) (both in M.2 slots) but no matter what I do the SATA SSD just doesn’t show up.
Both are set to GPT and both PCs are set to UEFI (at least hope so), also tried wiping it clean and formatted the SATA SSD on the PC that recognised it, reinstalled arch on that SSD also, still nothing.
Can anybody recommend anything else?

Are you sure the PC where it isn't recognized supports M.2 SATA drives? Likely it only supports NVMe.

I have a motherboard with 2 x M.2 slots. One seems to be NVMe only, the other is NVMe or SATA until I enabled Thunderbolt support, at that point, both M.2 support NVMe only  - perhaps read your motherboard documentation to see if it too has some restraints on combinations of add ons

Yea thats probably the issue, it says that both slots are PCLe so thats only for NVMe if i am correct. Thanks for both replies, I hadnt thought of that at all.

It sounds like a compatibility issue with your SATA SSD and the motherboard or BIOS settings on your first PC. Check if the SATA SSD is properly seated and if the motherboard BIOS recognizes it. Ensure the SATA port is enabled in BIOS settings and try different SATA ports if available. If it works on the second PC, the SSD itself is likely fine, focusing the issue on the first PC's configuration or hardware compatibility.

Not a good idea to write an answer worse or incomplete when compared to the comments already posted.
